# Android library proguard package obfuscation produces a.a.a.a.a collision

Tags: android, proguard, android-library

I'm writing 2 Android libraries. When I obfuscate both, the obfuscated code in both of them contains a class named `a.a.a.a.a` which causes the following error when trying to use both libraries in the same application:

> Duplicate class a.a.a.a.a found in modules classes.jar (lib1) and classes.jar (lib2)

How can I prevent `Proguard` from obfuscating the first 3 packages to end up with:

`my.domain.lib1.a.a` and `my.domain.lib2.a.a`?

**Edit:** The obfuscation is happening as part of building the libraries, not while building the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved by putting `-repackageclasses my.domain.lib#.ofs` in the `proguard-rules` file of each library while replaceing `#` with `1` and `2` respectivly. This will move all the obfuscated classes into the `my.domain.lib#.ofs` package while all the non-obfuscated classes will remain in their original packages and you're guaranteed to have no collisions.

As the `Proguard` [documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage) states:

> **-repackageclasses [package_name]**
>
> Specifies to repackage all class files that are renamed, by moving them into the single given package.

Another solution is to use `-keeppackagenames`. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to make it keep **only the first 3 packages**.

See the `Proguard` [documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage):

> **-keeppackagenames [package_filter]**
>
> Specifies not to obfuscate the given package names.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to the `proguard-rules.pro` file.

```
-keeppackagenames
```