# R8: Type com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface is defined multiple times:

Tags: flutter, apk

I am having this issue [bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFtw9.png) while running FLutter build apk.

Here is my pubsec.yaml files:
[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo9OJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though this is an issue with flutter_qr_reader indeed. There are several [related issues open](https://github.com/hetian9288/flutter_qr_reader/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+OpenCameraInterface), and it seems as though this is stemming from it literally having a class with the same name as a class from one of its dependency, and the dependency has the same namespace as flutter_qr_reader, so this may be causing the clash. I would follow the guidance in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510469/duplicate-class-found-in-modules-with-r8-enabled).

The class in flutter_qr_reader is: [OpenCameraInterface](https://github.com/hetian9288/flutter_qr_reader/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface.java).
The class from zxing-android-embedded is: [OpenCameraInterface](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/zxing-android-embedded/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/open/OpenCameraInterface.java). You can see this is a dependency of flutter_qr_reader [here](https://github.com/hetian9288/flutter_qr_reader/blob/e568f90723d9715bd3496877d1b23bffd09e88e2/android/build.gradle#L38).